# Significant Figures in Numerical Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, tostring

I am trying to make a calculator of sorts where you perform an operation and the code returns an answer that follows the rules of significant figures. Here is a boiled down portion of what I have coded:

```
var x = 0.002.toString().split(""); //to convert the number to a list

for(i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {
  if(x[i] != 0 || ".") {
    x.splice(0, i);
    { break; }
  }
}
```

The for loop is supposed to delete all of the non-significant 0's at the beginning, but it isn't working and I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: I don't think `toString()` ever returns insignificant zeroes.

Comment: `split` "converts" to an Array, not a list...

Comment: A significant figure is concept used in science to represent the accuracy of data. For the number 0.002, the only significant figure is the 2, so I am trying to get rid of the zeros so I have only significant figures left. Hopefully, I will be able to substitute the 0.002 with any other number less than 1 and greater than 0.

Comment: Why did you surround `break;` with `{` and `}`?

Comment: I'd add braces to make sure `(x[i] != 0 || ".")` tests exactly what I want - unless you are an expert on operator precedences...
Also, to not have to re-think - either you in the future, or anyone reading your code, including me/us.

Comment: You are looping with condition length and you are changing it in the loop = very iffy...
You are splicing `i`, are you sure you didn't mean `1`?
How about using `shift`?

Comment: I don't know what the `{}` do for the `break;`, that's just how I saw it on W3schools

Comment: Do you want one digit or from that one until the end?
"0.00257" => "2" or "257"?
`(0.00257).toString().replace(/^[0.]*/g,"").charAt(0)` or `(0.00257).toString().replace(/^[0.]*/g,"")`.

Comment: I would want the 257, what does the code you wrote do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if( x[i] != 0 || ".")
```

always succeeds because `"."` is always truthy. Try

```
if( !(x[i] === '0' || x[i] === '.')  )
```

to check if the character is neither a zero nor decimal point.